# The 'inverted' attribute is not recognized if a \DefineName abbreviation is used in an AMSRefs \bib entry

Tags: bibliographies, acronyms, key-value, amsrefs

In Section 8.1 of the AMSRefs [package documentation](https://ctan.um.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf), it is explained that to properly typeset author names that are to be written with the family name first, one should set the attribute `inverted` on that name; for example: `author={Li, Lian Jie}*{inverted={yes}}` will typeset correctly as 'Li Lian Jie' (and not as 'Li, Lian Jie' or 'Lian Jie Li'). Trying to use `author={Li Lian Jie}` to force the correct name will not work if, for instance, the option `initials` or the option `alphabetic` is called.

In Section 8.4, it is explained that one can write `\DefineName{dmj}{Jones, David M.}` and then use the abbreviation as `author={dmj}` in any `\bib` entry.

However, when I use an abbreviation in a `\bib` entry, the `inverted` attribute is not recognized. This happens even if there are multiple authors in a `\bib` entry and any one name is entered using an abbreviation, and even if that name is not the one to which the `inverted` attribute is being passed. Here's an MCVE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsrefs}

\DefineName{aut-f}{Author, First}
\DefineName{aut-s}{Author, Second}

\begin{document}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\raggedright

\bib{art1}{article}{
    author={Author, First}*{inverted={yes}},
    author={Author, Second}*{inverted={yes}},
    title={Title of the paper},
    journal={Journal of interesting results},
    volume={10},
    date={2021},
    number={3},
    pages={8\ndash 11},
    review={\MR{12345}},
}

\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

The output for the above example looks like this:

> Author First and Author Second, *Title of the paper*, Journal of interesting results **10** (2021), no. 3, 8–11. MR12345

Now, if I write `author={aut-f}` instead of `author={Author, First}`, the output changes to:

> First Author and Second Author, *Title of the paper*, Journal of interesting results **10** (2021), no. 3, 8–11. MR12345

That is, it behaves as if the `inverted` attribute is not passed to any of the entries. The output remains as above regardless of how I mix and match the `inverted` attributes with the abbreviations.

I also tried adding `*{inverted={yes}}` to the `\DefineName` commands, but that throws out `LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}`.

**Question:** How can I get the `inverted` attribute to work with the `\DefineName` abbreviations?

---

I tried looking at the [documented source](https://ctan.asis.ai/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrefs.pdf), but I was not really able to gather anything of use on my own. I noticed that `\DefineSimpleKey{prop}{inverted}` is defined on line 236, and we have on lines 2450–2461:

```
\def\set@name@a#1{%
    \begingroup
        \get@current@properties
        \select@auxlanguage
        \def\@tempa{yes}%
        \ifx\@tempa\prop’inverted
            \setbib@nameBE
        \else
            #1%
        \fi
    \endgroup
}
```

But, I'm not sure how to relate this to the definition of `\DefineName` given on lines 1244–1246:

```
\newcommand{\DefineName}[2]{%
    \bib*{#1}{name}{name={#2}}%
}
```

---

I also looked at the [documentation](https://ctan.asis.ai/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/rkeyval.pdf) for the `rkeyval` package to find out whether the key value option `*{inverted={yes}}` needs to somehow be added to the definition of the command `\DefineName`, but once again I didn't get much out of it (being far too much of a novice). For instance, on page 3 of the `rkeyval` documentation the following is mentioned:

> Test for a trailing option marked by a star. Usage:
>
> ```
> \newcommand{\blub}[1]{\star@{\blubaux{#1}}{default}}
> ```
>
> Arg 1 of `\star@` is the code to be run, arg 2 is the default value of the option (could be empty). If arg 1 is `\moo`, this test discards a star and expands to `\moo` if a star is found, or expands to `\moo{#2}` if not. As the example shows, arg 1 need not be a single token.
>
> ```
> 10 \def\star@#1#2{%
> 11     \def\star@a##1{#1}%
> 12     \def\star@b{#1{#2}}%
> 13     \futurelet\@let@token\star@test
> 14 }
> 15
> 16 \def\star@test{\ifx*\@let@token \let\star@b\star@a\fi \star@b}
> ```

Perhaps this is relevant? I'm honestly quite lost.

---

I also noticed that if I define a command called `\DefineInvertedName` analogously to `\DefineName` as

```
\newcommand{\DefineInvertedName}[2]{%
    \bib*{#1}{name}{name={#2}*{inverted={yes}}}%
}
```

followed by adding

```
\DefineInvertedName{aut-f1}{Author, First}
\DefineInvertedName{aut-s1}{Author, Second}
```

to the preamble in the MCVE above, and using `author={aut-f1}` and `author={aut-s1}` in the `\bib` entry, gives this as the output:

> First Author and Author Second, *Title of the paper*, Journal of interesting results **10** (2021), no. 3, 8–11. MR12345

That is, only the last author entry is inverted. The same happens when I create a `\bib` entry with more than two authors: only the last author entry is inverted. This is possibly a byproduct of the way multiple author entries are strung together by AMSRefs, but I'm not able to pinpoint exactly why it is so.